# countering human-paid spammers

Tags: php, spam

after i patched up recaptcha in my community, it seems spam is still coming from nowhere and the only thing i can imagine causing it is a paid human being to spam, any ideas how to prevent these bastards ?

Comment: "any ideas how to prevent these bastards ?" haha

Comment: Are you going to stop us? haha :) No, seriously you can't do much things to protect your web from 'human-bots'. You can also pay counter-human-spammers team to fight against spammers but the only way to stop them completely is to shut-down your web.

Comment: If a CAPTCHA doesn't solve the problem, add more of it. - No really. Add one captcha per detected link. That's usually enough to frustrate manual link spam.

Comment: The only effective measure against spam is, sadly, making them pay. Spam works because it does not cost anything. This can either be addressed via measures at registration that annoy the hell out of your legitimate users, or by fighting where you have a chance of winning, in the spammers' clients domain. You can cost the company that employs the spammer a lot of money with very little effort. If enough people do that on a regular base, spam will become less attractive. Other than that, it is better to just delete spam and ignore it, rather than annoy legitimate users with harder captchas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming and probably would find better answers on another SE.

Comment: @Trilarion and deleted it will be :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than IP blocking, which isn't very effective, I would suggest using a community effort like StackOverflow uses.  Allow users to flag content, and it will help the problem.

You can also require unique email with an activation link, if you don't already.

Comment: Of course they can, but if you require a unique email address per registration, they will have to create a new email each time they get blocked by the community.  This is assuming you block email services that don't require registration, like bugmenot, etc.  You can watch for abused domains or IPs and block them, and it will quickly become tiresome to the spammer.

Comment: unless they made a spambot that beats the crap out of recaptcha, but i'll try your suggestion, another thing, what do you think about bad-behavior script ?

Comment: I've never used bad-behavior scripts, sorry.  I've never had to do much after allowing community flagging.  That really is the best way to counter these things, IMHO.  But it wouldn't hurt to try.  I hear they integrate easily with PHP.

Comment: i've integrated it in my script, i'll see the result and post back

Comment: Try the community approach.  I promise you won't be disappointed.  You allow a user to flag, and when a percentage of flags vs. views hits a threshold, you remove the offending post.  The percentages and minimum flags required will depend on your community, so play with it a little and see how it works.

Comment: i'm sorry that i didn't clarify it more, there is no active community at the moment =D